# `std::shared_ptr`: is not a valid template type argument for parameter `_Ty`

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

**Errors**

`Hero`: undeclared identifier

`std::shared_ptr`: `Hero` is not a valid template type argument for parameter `_Ty`

unary `->`: `std::shared_ptr` does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

`attackInput`, `getSkill` os not a member of `std::shared_ptr`

`void my::Weapon::hit(std::shared_ptr,std::shared_ptr)`: cannot convert argument 1 from `std::shard_ptr<my::Hero>` to `std::shared_ptr`

**Source.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "Hero.h"

void checkLife(my::Hero* hero)
{
    if (hero->is_dead())
    {
        delete hero;
        hero = nullptr;
    }
    if (hero == nullptr)
    {
        srand(time(0));
        int rand = 1 + std::rand() % 40;

        if (rand > 0 && rand <= 10) hero = new my::King();
        else if (rand > 10 && rand <= 20) hero = new my::Queen();
        else if (rand > 20 && rand <= 30) hero = new my::Troll();
        else if (rand > 30 && rand <= 40) hero = new my::Knight();
    }
}

int main()
{
    my::Hero* hero = nullptr;
    my::Hero* enemy = nullptr;

    while (true)
    {
        checkLife(hero);
        checkLife(enemy);

        hero->attackOutput(std::shared_ptr<my::Hero>(enemy));
        enemy->attackOutput(std::shared_ptr<my::Hero>(hero));

        system("cls");
        std::cout << hero->getName() << "`s health - " << hero->getHealth() << std::endl;
        std::cout << hero->getName() << "`s health - " << hero->getHealth() << std::endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    if (hero != nullptr) delete hero;
    if (enemy != nullptr) delete enemy;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Hero.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include "Weapon.h"

namespace my
{
    class Hero abstract
    {
    protected:
        std::shared_ptr<Weapon> weapon;
        std::string name;
        int health;
        int skill;
        int pressure;
        int nobleness;
        int beauty;

        virtual void attack(int damage)
        {
            srand(time(0));
            this->health -= damage + rand() % 20 - this->getPressurel();
        }
    public:
        Hero(std::string name, int health, int skill, int pressure, int nobleness, int beauty)
        {
            this->name = name;
            this->health = health;
            this->skill = skill;
            this->pressure = pressure;
            this->nobleness = nobleness;
            this->beauty = beauty;
        }
        std::string getName() const
        {
            return this->name;
        }
        int getHealth() const
        {
            return this->health;
        }
        int getSkill() const
        {
            return this->skill;
        }
        int getPressurel() const
        {
            return this->pressure;
        }
        int getNobleness() const
        {
            return this->nobleness;
        }
        int getBeauty() const
        {
            return this->beauty;
        }
        void attackInput(const int damage)
        {
            this->attack(damage);
        }
        void attackOutput(std::shared_ptr<Hero> enemy)
        {
            std::shared_ptr<Hero> thisHero(this);
            this->weapon->hit(std::shared_ptr<Hero>(thisHero), enemy);

        }
        virtual void takeWeapon(std::shared_ptr<Weapon> weapon)
        {
            this->weapon = weapon;
        }
        bool is_dead()
        {
            if (this->health <= 0) return true;
            else return false;
        }
    };

    class King : public Hero
    {
    public:
        King() : Hero("King", 300, 2, 4, 10, 15) {}
    };

    class Queen : public Hero
    {
    public:
        Queen() : Hero("Queen", 300, 2, 4, 10, 15) {}
    };

    class Troll : public Hero
    {
    public:
        Troll() : Hero("Troll", 300, 2, 4, 10, 15) {}
    };

    class Knight : public Hero
    {
    public:
        Knight() : Hero("Knight", 300, 2, 4, 10, 15) {}
    };
}
```

**Weapon.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Hero.h"

namespace my
{
    class Weapon abstract
    {
    protected:
        const int damage;
        int wear;
    public:
        Weapon(int damage, int weight, int size, int wear) : damage(damage)
        {
            this->wear = wear;
        }
        Weapon() : Weapon(1, 1, 1, 1) {}

        virtual void setWeaponWear(int wear)
        {
            this->wear = wear;
        }
        virtual int getWeaponDamage() const
        {
            return this->damage;
        }
        virtual int getWeaponWear() const
        {
            return this->wear;
        }

        virtual void hit(std::shared_ptr<Hero> me, std::shared_ptr<Hero> enemy) = 0;
    };

    class Knife : public Weapon // NOZH
    {
    protected:
    public:
        virtual void hit(std::shared_ptr<Hero> me, std::shared_ptr<Hero> enemy)
        {
            int damage = this->damage * me->getBeauty();
            this->wear--;
            enemy->attackInput(damage);
        }
    };

    class Bow : public Weapon // LUCK
    {
    protected:
    public:
        virtual void hit(std::shared_ptr<Hero> me, std::shared_ptr<Hero> enemy)
        {
            int damage = this->damage * me->getNobleness();
            this->wear--;
            enemy->attackInput(damage);
        }
    };

    class Ax : public Weapon // TOPOR
    {
    protected:
    public:
        virtual void hit(std::shared_ptr<Hero> me, std::shared_ptr<Hero> enemy)
        {
            int damage = this->damage * me->getPressurel();
            this->wear--;
            enemy->attackInput(damage);
        }
    };

    class Sword : public Weapon // MECH
    {
    protected:
    public:
        virtual void hit(std::shared_ptr<Hero> me, std::shared_ptr<Hero> enemy)
        {
            int damage = this->damage * me->getSkill();
            this->wear--;
            enemy->attackInput(damage);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Circular include dependencies usually (a) id potential design flaws and (b) cause problems because of (a). This is no exception. Hero.h includes Weapon.h, which includes Hero.h. You need a forward decl.

Comment: `checkLife(my::Hero* hero)` gets `hero` (the pointer) by value. `delete` will delete the old `Hero` at the address, but the new assignment is to the local `hero` in `checkLife`. Also, do you expect `checkLife` to be called with a `nullptr`? The code is currently ambiguous. There's an explicit test, but it is _after_ the use of the pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by @WhozCraig you have a circular dependency. You need `Weapon.h` in `Hero.h` and `Hero.h` in `Weapon.h`.

The only reason you need `Hero.h` in `Weapon.h`. Is for the `hit(...)` function. The best solution would be to declare the hit function somewhere else. Right now the best place would be to add it to the `Hero`. A hero has a weapon and attacks with that weapon another hero, a weapon itself can't attack, so just from the semantics it makes more sense to have the hit function inside the hero class.

You can probably get it to compile by splitting the code up into a header (.h) and source file (.cpp) and having a forward declaration of `Hero` in `Weaopon.h`. But this will not fix the underlying problem and the design is still flawed and will probably cause even more problems if functionality is extended.